# Promieses isn't work like it should Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with promises in Javascript. I wanted to make a function that firstly load the site in HTML using fetch and after this function is adding an event listener to the button. The point is that this button doesn't exist because it is loading by fetch function. I tried to make this using promises but it still didn't work.

signUp.js:

```
import { load } from './modules/load.js';
import { Authentication } from './classes/Authentication.js';
signUpButton.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function () {
        const signUp = () =>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            load.site('pages/signUp/signUp.html', content); //this is loading the site in html
            resolve();
        })
    }
    
        


        signUp().then( // and this is executing too fast because the element to which I want to add listener isn't exist.
        function(){
            console.log('promise')
        document.querySelector('.signup-form').addEventListener(
            'click',
            function () {
                const password = document.querySelector('.input-password');
                const retypePassword = document.querySelector(
                    '.input-retype-password'
                );
                const email = document.querySelector('.input-email');
                const login = document.querySelector('.input-login');
                const authPassword = new Authentication(password);
                const authEmail = new Authentication(email);
                const authLogin = new Authentication(login);
                if (
                    password.value === retypePassword.value &&
                    authLogin.validate(6, 18, []) &&
                    authPassword.validate(6, 18, []) &&
                    authEmail.validate(1, 100, ['@', '.'])
                ) {
                    firebase
                        .auth()
                        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
                        .then((userCredential) => {
                            // Signed in
                            var user = userCredential.user;
                            // ...
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            var errorCode = error.code;
                            var errorMessage = error.message;
                            // ..
                        });
                }
            },
            false
        )});
    },
    false
);
```

load.js

```
export const load = (function () {
    const site = function (url, parent) {
        fetch(url)
        .then(response =>{
            return response.text()
        })
        .then(data =>{
            parent.innerHTML = data;
        })
    };

    return {
        site: site,
    };
})();
```

Comment: `return fetch(url)...`?

Comment: `load.site` doesn't return anything, once you make it return a Promise, then you won't need to create one in the other code

Comment: The Promise in your signUp function resolves immediately, it doesn't wait for `load.site()` to finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the `fetch(url)` from in the `load.js`

```js
export const load = (function () {
  const site = function (url, parent) {
    return fetch(url)
      .then(response => {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(data => {
        parent.innerHTML = data;
      });
  };

  return {
    site: site,
  };
})();
```

Then you should return load.site()

```js
signUpButton.addEventListener("click", onClickSignUp, false);

function onClickSignUp() {
  const signUp = () => {
    return load.site("pages/signUp/signUp.html", content) //this is loading the site in html
    });
  };

  signUp().then();
}
```

Comment: @Tsuso, you are welcome. If you find it useful to others, please accept the answer as well.